# React Native Google / Facebook Login

Tags: javascript, react-native, facebook, authentication, google-signin

I'm quit new in React native but I would like to set up Google login but what I did didn't seem to work.
(That will be a long post haha )

**For Google Login:**

I tried several tutorials on YouTube (this one for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DN9dQ_6ezvA)

> "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth
> 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.
> See
> [https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project."](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.%22)

I tried a lot of thing but it's really hard for me. So if someone could give me some help? Thanks you in advance guys, I continue the research on my side

Here is my code:

```
WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();

export default function GoogleFunc({largeur}) {
  const fontRegular = require("../../assets/Manrope-Regular.ttf");
  const fontBold = require("../../assets/Manrope-Bold.ttf");

  const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    ManropeRegular: fontRegular,
    ManropeBold: fontBold,
  });

  const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = React.useState();
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = React.useState();
  const [request, response, prompAsync] = Google.useIdTokenAuthRequest({
    androidClientId:
      "ANDROID_CLIENT_ID",
    iosClientId:
      "CLIENT_CLIENT_ID",
    clientId:
      "CLIENT_ID",
  });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (response?.type === "success") {
      console.log("response: ", response.params);
      setAccessToken(response.params.id_token);
      accessToken && fetchUserInfo();
    }
  }, [response, accessToken]);

  async function fetchUserInfo() {
    console.log("test222");
    let response = await fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me", {
      headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`},
    });
    const useInfo = await response.json();
    console.log("useinfo: ", useInfo);
    setUserInfo(useInfo);
  }

  const ShowUserInfo = () => {
    if (userInfo) {
      console.log("userinfooofofof: ", userInfo);
      return (
        <View style={styles.userInfo}>
          <Image source={{uri: userInfo.picture}} style={styles.profilePic} />
          <Text>Welcome {userInfo.name}</Text>
          <Text>{userInfo.email}</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {userInfo && <ShowUserInfo />}
      {userInfo == null && (
        <>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={[styles.googleBtn, {width: largeur}]}
            disabled={!request}
            onPress={() => {
              prompAsync();
            }}
          >
            <Image
              style={{
                height: height * 0.024,
                width: width * 0.057,
                left: width * 0.035,
                top: height * 0.013,
              }}
              source={require("../../assets/images/google-logo.png")}
            />
            <Text
              style={{
                textAlign: "center",
                fontFamily: "ManropeSemiBold",
                fontSize: 17,
                color: "#262626",
                bottom: height * 0.01,
              }}
            >
              Continuer avec Google
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </>
      )}
    </View>
  );
}
```

**For Facebook:**

I tried to set up the login with / without firebase but I already got the same issue : an error ...
I'm trying to solve it since last week but I don't understand how can i fix these problems ...

Here's my code **without Firebase**:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ActivityIndicator,
} from "react-native";
import * as Facebook from "expo-facebook";

export default function FacebookFunc() {
  const [isLoggedin, setLoggedinStatus] = useState(false);
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null);
  const [isImageLoading, setImageLoadStatus] = useState(false);

  async function faceookLogIn() {
    try {
      await Facebook.initializeAsync({
        appId: "APP ID",
      });
      const {type, token, expirationDate, permissions, declinedPermissions} =
        await Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync({
          permissions: ["public_profile"],
        });
      if (type === "success") {
        // Get the user's name using Facebook's Graph API
        const response = await fetch(
          `https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=${token}`
        );
        Alert.alert("Logged in!", `Hi ${(await response.json()).name}!`);
      } else {
        // type === 'cancel'
      }
    } catch ({message}) {
      alert(`Facebook Login Error: ${message}`);
    }
  }

  logout = () => {
    setLoggedinStatus(false);
    setUserData(null);
    setImageLoadStatus(false);
  };

  return isLoggedin ? (
    userData ? (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image
          style={{width: 200, height: 200, borderRadius: 50}}
          source={{uri: userData.picture.data.url}}
          onLoadEnd={() => setImageLoadStatus(true)}
          // GERER QUAND MARCHERA
        />
        <ActivityIndicator
          size={"large"}
          color={"#0000ff"}
          animating={!isImageLoading}
          style={{position: "absolute"}}
        />
        <Text style={{fontSize: 22, marginVertical: 10}}>
          Hi {userData.name}!
        </Text>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.logoutBtn} onPress={logout}>
          <Text style={{color: "#fff"}}>Logout</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    ) : null
  ) : (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.loginBtn} onPress={faceookLogIn}>
        <Text style={{color: "#fff", textAlign: "center"}}>
          Login with facebook
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {},
  loginBtn: {
    backgroundColor: "#4267b2",
    paddingVertical: 10,
    borderRadius: 10,
    width: "95%",
  },
  logoutBtn: {
    backgroundColor: "grey",
    includeFontPadding: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    borderRadius: 20,
    position: "absolute:",
    bottom: 0,
    marginBottom: 200,
  },
});
```

And here my code when I trying **with Firebase**:

The error:

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
> TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'LoginManager.logInWithPermissions')

The code:

```
import React from "react";
import {LoginManager, AccessToken} from "react-native-fbsdk-next";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Button,
} from "react-native";
import {
  getAuth,
  signInWithCredential,
  FacebookAuthProvider,
} from "firebase/auth";
import "expo-dev-client";

import app from "./firebaseSetup";

export default function App() {
  const SignInWithFB = async () => {
    const result = await LoginManager.logInWithPermissions([
      "public_profile",
      "email",
    ]);
    if (result.isCancelled) {
      throw new Error("User cancelled login");
    }
    const data = await AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
    if (!data) {
      throw new Error("Something went wrong obtaining access token");
    }
    const auth = getAuth(app);

    const credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(data.accessToken);
    const user = await signInWithCredential(auth, credential);
    console.log(user);
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Button title="Sign in with facebook" onPress={SignInWithFB}></Button>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

I initialize my firebaseSetup like this:

```
import {initializeApp} from "firebase/app";

// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: "",
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export default app;
```

I continue my research by my side but if someone could help me with this problem (which is probably stupid), thanks you in advance...

PS: There is the error for Facebook without firebase:

> Facebook Login Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating'_ExponentFacebook.default.InitializeAsync')

Comment: What is the library that you use for facebook? Did you check its documentation whether you initialize the objects correctly? Seems like there's some step missing during initialization.

Comment: Are you using Expo or CLI. Bcz the FB Lib you are using is for CLI Native not for EXPO

Comment: @MichalTrojanowski I think but there is probably something wrong. I'm using "expo-facebook"

Comment: @SuyashVashishtha I'm using expo. I import Facebook lib with this import : 
"import * as Facebook from "expo-facebook";"

Comment: @Nicolas If you are using Expo, use auth season for social logins, I will add the code ( component ) for it in answers but you have to adjust it according to your needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use expo auth session to implement oAuth in Expo

```js
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import Fontisto from '@expo/vector-icons/Fontisto';
import { TouchableOpacity,StyleSheet, Alert } from 'react-native';
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';
import * as Facebook from 'expo-auth-session/providers/facebook';
import {makeRedirectUri, ResponseType } from 'expo-auth-session';
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";

WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();

export default function FacebookAuth(){

  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

      const [request, response, promptAsync] = Facebook.useAuthRequest({
        responseType: ResponseType.Token,
        clientId: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
        scopes: ['public_profile', 'email'],
        redirectUri: makeRedirectUri({ useProxy: true })
      },
      { useProxy: true });
    
      React.useEffect(() => {
        if (response?.type === 'success') {
          setIsLoading(true);
          const accessToken = response.authentication.accessToken;

        console.log(accessToken);
        }
      }, [response]);


    return(
      <>
        <TouchableOpacity disabled={!request} style={styles.socialLoginButton}
        onPress={() => {
            promptAsync();
          }}
        >
             <Fontisto name='facebook' color={'white'} size={25}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    socialLoginButton:{
        margin:3,
        backgroundColor:'blue',
        padding:10,
        borderRadius:50,
        width:50,
        height:50,
        justifyContent:'center',
        alignItems:'center',
        margin:10,
      }
})
```

Here's the code for it, you have to configure it according to your needs.
here's the link for expo auth session. - [here](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/authentication/#facebook)

Comment: Okay I tried your code and changed my facebook app configuration. I think it works I got return "success" and an accessToken. Do you know if it's possible to receive the user informations like the email and the username ?

Comment: Yeah, Facebook allow us to do that. But it has a separate api , you have to send acessToken in it with a client token/secret and it will return the desired info

Comment: Okay thanks you I will search by my side.

Answer (score 0):

For login with Google, I think the problem lies with this code:

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
    if (response?.type === "success") {
      setAccessToken(response.params.id_token);
      accessToken && fetchUserInfo();
    }
  }, [response, accessToken]);
```

You use the `id_token` from the response, and you should be using the access token. Also, I think you could split this into two `useEffect` methods:

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
    if (response?.type === "success") {
      setAccessToken(response.params.access_token);
    }
  }, [response]);

 React.useEffect(() => {
      fetchUserInfo();
 }, [accessToken]);
```

The other effect will trigger only when the state of `accessToken` changes. If it's possible that you change the state to an empty value then you should retain the null check.

As for Facebook and Firebase issues — are you sure you followed all the required setup for these libraries? Just skimming through the documentation shows that there are quite a few things that should be configured before you can call the libs. From your error messages, it seems that the libraries are not configured and initialized properly.

Comment: I already tried to use response.params.access_token but it doesn't exist. When I console.log(response), there is not any params.access_token. I show you my console.log:

authuser
: 
"0"
"expo_session"
: 
""
id_token
: 
"id_token"
prompt
: 
"none"
state
: 
"EgGKyxil1f"